# How to send letters plus keyboard combination to adb shell?

Tags: shell, adb

To run my program from Linux command-line I do:

- adb shell
- cd /data/
- ./devprog count

To stop I need to type the letter "T" then hit enter otherwise the devprog keeps running forever. I want to find a way to run the devprog for three seconds and then exit devprog properly by sending the keyboard keys "T + Enter". How can I accomplish this or is it even possible to do with the shell?

I tried the followings:

- timeout 3s adb shell ./data/devprog count
- adb shell ./data/devprog count & timeout 3s | T

I don't know what else to do to run my program for three seconds then exit the command with the keyword combination.

Note: I tried adb shell ./data/devprog count & sleep 3 | xargs adb shell kill. This will stop the program but it will not return any outputs from devporg.

Comment: I wouldn't describe T+enter as a "keyboard combination". A combination generally means two keys held down at the same time, not pressed in sequence. Only a limited number of combinations (involving explicit modifier keys, like shift or ctrl) can be meaningfully represented in a terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
adb shell < <(
  printf '%s\n' \
    'cd /data || exit' \
    'exec ./devprog count'
  sleep 3
  printf '%s\n' T
)
```

Explaining the nonobvious parts of this:

- `<(...)` is a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst); the shell replaces it with a filename that refers to a FIFO from which the output of `...` can be read.
- `adb shell < <(...)` thus runs `adb shell`, with its input redirected from a process substitution with the embedded code.
- `printf '%s\n' "some text" "some more text"` writes two lines, first `some text`, then `some more text`. We use this to write the commands we want to unconditionally run.
- Using `|| exit` on the `cd` prevents the script from continuing to run if the `cd` fails, so we don't invoke commands that might behave unpredictably outside their intended environment.
- Using `exec` in `exec ./devprog count` replaces the remote shell with a copy of `./devprog`, so we don't need to worry about what happens if `./devprog` exits early and puts us back in the shell: with that change made, it's guaranteed that when `./devprog` exits, so does the remote shell.

Why did we use a process substitution and not a heredoc? That's because a heredoc is fully evaluated before execution starts, so embedding something like `$(sleep 3)` in a heredoc would delay `adb` from starting, but it wouldn't create a delay *while `adb` was running*.

Comment: Can I run this shell script from the commandline with one single line? such as: 
adb shell < <(  printf '%s\n' \  'cd /data || exit' \  'exec ./devprog count' sleep 3 printf '%s\n' T)

It will be super useful if I can run this in single line from the commandline instead of a shell script.

Comment: Yes, you can run it at the command line. The usual restrictions apply (needing to use `;`s as command separators where you don't have newlines, etc). And leave out the backslashes where you don't actually have a linebreak. The point of a backslash at the end of the line is to tell the shell to treat the two lines of script as part of the same command; if you're putting it all on one line you don't need or want that.

Comment: @Dav, ...so, in this case that one line would be something like: `adb shell < <(printf '%s\n' 'cd /data || exit' 'exec ./devprog count' && sleep 3 && printf '%s\n' T)` (switching to `&&`s so we exit early instead of sleeping if `adb` isn't actually running and available for the first `printf` to write to).